# Write a function properly with the sets above the function itself

Tags: math-mode

Is there a way to write a function like this in Latex but with aligning the arrows:
[image: Function]

I tried to write this code but I can't get the bar on the left and my arrows aren't align neither...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
     S \colon \mathbf{R}^+ \to \mathbf{R} \\
     h \mapsto h \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} f(nh)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

which results into this:
[image: What I get]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[S:\left\vert \begin{aligned}
  \mathbb{R}^+ & \to \mathbb{R} \\
  h & \mapsto h\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} f(nh)
\end{aligned} \right.\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can tweak `tikx-cd` to do it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
S \colon \left|\,
\begin{tikzcd}[
  row sep=-0.5ex,
  column sep=1.5em,
  every matrix/.append style={inner sep=-0.5em},
  /tikz/column 1/.style={anchor=east},
  /tikz/column 2/.style={anchor=west},
]
  \mathbf{R}^+ \arrow[r] & \mathbf{R} \\
   h \arrow[r,mapsto] &  h \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} f(nh)
\end{tikzcd}
\right.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]